# Tables and stored procedures not getting included in the generated script

Tags: sql-server, database-project

I have created a SQL Server database project using Visual Studio 2015. The underlying database is SQL Server 2016. I have created the project by importing an existing database into the project. I have the structure ready. When I click on publish and select generate, it doesn't include the tables and stored procedures in the generated script. I can see one odd script added. Am I missing something?

Please see the screenshot of my project

[image]

Comment: Could it be because those objects already exist in the database and hence it's not getting generated in script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been now resolved. The mistake i was making is importing the data objects from the database and trying to generate the script pointing to the same database. It was not generating the scripts since the database objects existed . Pointing to another database helped me generating the scripts.